# django-storages s3 403 forbidden error

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I am using django-storages to upload static files to AWS S3. I followed the tutorials and was able to successfully upload and retrieve the static files for the admin page.

I then created a static directory in my django project, added some bootstrap files and ran collectstatic. I can see that the bootstrap files were all successfully stored to my S3 bucket. However, when I try to run my app (both locally and on Heroku), the bootstrap files fail with a get 403 forbidden error.

The admin files are stored in an admin folder within the same S3 bucket and are retrieved with no problems. What might account for this discrepancy? I am new to s3, so perhaps I am doing something wrong there.

I have confirmed that my AWS keys are working.

My settings.py are as follows:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'punchline-app'
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True 
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = 'https://punchline-app.s3.amazonaws.com/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'https://punchline-app.s3.amazonaws.com/static/admin/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,"static"),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Comment: Is this the correct url (https://punchline-app.s3.amazonaws.com/static/admin/css/base.css) for one of the admin static files? I am getting permission denied errors if so. This post might also help shed some light involving S3 bucket permissions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167493/access-denied-error-with-amazon-s3

Comment: The permissions seem fine. I noticed there is no static folder in my bucket however. I have solved the problem by changing my STATIC_URL url accordingly (dropping the 'static' from the path). Strangely, the ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX url still has static in the path and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your access keys sorted out like this in your settings.py file?

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
```

And did you set your env variables in heroku? e.g.

```
heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='<put your key here>'
```